# What is causing this module (NumberTheory) installation error in cabal?

Tags: haskell, cabal

I am getting the following error trying to install a number theory module for Haskell

```
PS C:\Users\prker\Desktop\Haskell SFs> cabal new-install NumberTheory -j1
Wrote tarball sdist to C:\Users\prker\Desktop\Haskell
SFs\dist-newstyle\sdist\Haskell-SFs-0.1.0.tar.gz
Resolving dependencies...
Build profile: -w ghc-8.6.5 -O1
In order, the following will be built (use -v for more details):
 - NumberTheory-0.1.0.1 (lib) (requires build)
Configuring library for NumberTheory-0.1.0.1..
Preprocessing library for NumberTheory-0.1.0.1..
Building library for NumberTheory-0.1.0.1..
[1 of 1] Compiling NumberTheory     ( NumberTheory.hs, dist\build\NumberTheory.o )

NumberTheory.hs:422:10: error:
    * Could not deduce (Semigroup (GaussInt a))
        arising from the superclasses of an instance declaration
      from the context: Monoid a
        bound by the instance declaration at NumberTheory.hs:422:10-42
    * In the instance declaration for `Monoid (GaussInt a)'
    |
422 | instance (Monoid a) => Monoid (GaussInt a) where
    |          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Warning: Some package(s) failed to build. Try rerunning with -j1 if you can't
see the error.
```

It seems like a syntax error in the module itself but that seems highly unlikely. I've tried reinstalling cabal and making sure all the other module are up to date.

Comment: You are likely compiling an old library with a modern compiler. In the early `base` versions there was no `Semigroup`, and only a `Monoid` that offered both `mempty` and `(<>)`, later the `(<>)` was  moved to a separate `Semigroup` typeclass. It is not a syntax error, it is simply the base library that changed, and thus calterec the "contracts" one must implement.

Comment: Ah, I see, on Hackage I hadn't noticed before but NumberTheory is for Haskell98. I will search for a more up to date number theory module.

Comment: Apparently the library was published in 2016, but they use a `base=4.*`, which is "too broad". So it is the dependencies that are not "well written".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the [information on *Hackage*](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/NumberTheory) the package was published in february 2016. At that time latest release of the [**`base`** package](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.2.0) was `base-4.8.2.0`. In that package, there is a [**`Monoid`** typeclass](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.2.0/docs/src/GHC.Base.html#Monoid):

> ```
> class Monoid a where
>         mempty  :: a
>         -- ^ Identity of 'mappend'
>         mappend :: a -> a -> a
>         -- ^ An associative operation
>         mconcat :: [a] -> a
> ```

But it thus does not require the members to be an instance of the `Semigroup` typeclass, in fact that typeclass did not yet exists.

Since [**`base-4.11.0.0`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.0.0), the definition has changed to:

> ```
> class Semigroup a => Monoid a where
>         -- | Identity of 'mappend'
>         mempty  :: a
>
>         -- | An associative operation
>         --
>         -- __NOTE__: This method is redundant and has the default
>         -- implementation @'mappend' = '(<>)'@ since /base-4.11.0.0/.
>         mappend :: a -> a -> a
>         mappend = (<>)
>         {-# INLINE mappend #-}
>
>         -- | Fold a list using the monoid.
>         --
>         -- For most types, the default definition for 'mconcat' will be
>         -- used, but the function is included in the class definition so
>         -- that an optimized version can be provided for specific types.
>         mconcat :: [a] -> a
>         mconcat = foldr mappend mempty
> ```

It thus requires types that are members of the `Monoid` typeclass to be members of the [**`Semigroup`** type class](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#t:Semigroup) as well. The library of course did not anticipate on that.

The reason that the system still aims to compile this is because the [package description](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/NumberTheory-0.1.0.1/NumberTheory.cabal) of the `NumberTheory`says:

> ```
>   build-depends:       base ==4.*, containers ==0.5.*, primes ==0.2.*
> ```

It thus assumes that it can build the software with any version of base with as version `4.*`, so `4.11` and beyond are still considered good candidates.

Comment: Thank you for this explanation, helpful for my understanding of the package system. I ended up fixing this problem by simply using a better kept package, specifically arithmoi-0.11.0.0 had what I needed.